# Frontend & Backend Website not launching after performing SYSTEM BACKUP

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, backup

I decided to perform a SYSTEM Backup via the admin of my website at 4:13am, even though I'm not so techy with Magento. It kept showing 'Please Wait' all the while. I went to bed, woke after 6hours and it was still the same. I left it for a long while till around 11:30pm and it was still showing 'Please Wait'. While it was performing the backup, I couldn't access both the frontend and backend of the website.

As I wasn't sure of what to do to bring the website back alive, I stopped the Backup at about 11:40pm by typing a different web address into the URL. Having done that, nothing seems to have changed and I still can't access both the backend & frontend.

Please I need some advice on what to do. Please do let me know if you require more clarification.

Comment: Maintenance.flag doesn't seem to be in the Magento installation folder.
 
I have also cleared the cache by deleting the var/cache and var/session but still the same. It gives HTTP 500 error message: Most likely causes: •The website is under maintenance. •The website has a programming error.

Comment: I have managed to resolved it by changing the permission for index.php fromm 666 to 644.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a shot in the dark, but is there a file called `maintenance.flag` in the root of your Magento installation folder? If so, delete it and everything should work.

Comment: I have read somewhere that I should delete the maintenance.flag but it doesn't appear in within the installation folder.

Comment: I have also cleared the cache by deleting the var/cache and var/session but still the same. It gives HTTP 500 error message:  Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error

Comment: I would check the logs in `/var/log/` and see if you can find a more detailed error message and a stack trace there.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments above, the original poster solved this problem by

> changing the permission for index.php fromm 666 to 644

This is likely a security precaution of their shared web host — many shared web hosts systems consider `666` an invalid permission and have special monitors in place to prevent users from serving such files.

Comment: SuExec, SuPHP and cPanel WHM all expect files (especially top level, directly executed PHP files) to not be world writable. Magento's got a function in `lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File.php` as `public function open($mode = \'w+\', $chmod = 0666)` that causes all the griefer goodness. A way around it is to run Magento's Cleanup tool [referenced midway down](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions) this recommended permissions settings page.